# Control and Alt works as Shift

Tags: keyboard, layout

I have this brand new backlight keyboard (Seisa DN-V710), the first time I plugged in (USB) all the fancy light and keys looks fine. In a very short time I notice both, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> function as Shift (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = C capital)

I tried to search how to change the driver, the layout, etc. But all my efforts ended when I look up the xev, the shift key; the control key and the alt key are mapped with "keycode 50"

Please, I don't know what else have to do, and I really like this keyboard...

Comment: Answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/648798/ctrl-and-alt-works-as-shift

Answer (score 0):

If all these keys are mapped to the same keycode, the Linux kernel cannot distinguish between them and you should contact the hardware vendor about this...

Comment: Or a new and better keyboard. =)

Comment: It's working on Windows...

Comment: Yeah, but they probably have a proprietary driver for Windows...  So if they didn't keep to the AT standard and need a special HID driver, you still need to contact the vendor to get the exact key-codes to write your own module (=open speak for "driver") or have them get you one

Answer (score 0):

Here is a manual approach that might fix this:

Type command `xmodmap` and find the offending modifiers (for example, `control` and `mod1`)

You can clear and reassign to the right keys like this:

For `control`:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear control'
xmodmap -e 'add control = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'add control = Control_R`
```

and for `alt`(if `alt` is `mod1`):

```
xmodmap -e 'clear mod1'
xmodmap -e 'add mod1 = Alt_L'
xmodmap -e 'add mod1 = Alt_R'
```

If this works, making changes persistent can be done according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/101877/819809) post.