# Need help swapping Alt and Ctrl

Tags: keyboard, xkb

Information seems a bit thin/outdated on this topic, specifically when it comes to why the command `setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl` doesn't work (doesn't work in tweak tool either). Many other `setxkbmap` options seem to work just fine. Any way to get this to work?

The `~/.Xmodmap` solution is finicky, constantly needs to be reapplied.  This shouldn't be that obscure/difficult, right?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93624/how-do-i-swap-left-ctrl-with-left-alt-on-my-keyboard